# Android: CameraBridgeViewBase FPS low

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

The FPS of the CameraBridgeViewBase is relative low (on a Nexus 4 phone ~10 FPS). If I use detectors on it, it will be much slower.

Is there a way to accelerate it? What are the alternatives with better FPS for image processing on Android plattform?